# Specify same email for different payments chained payments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using paypal chained payment in my app,

I am taking 2 emails and 3 amounts,

I am placing my code below

```
NSArray *emailArray = [NSArray abc@def.com,def@abc.com, nil];

NSArray *amountArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3.13",@"0.10",@"0.03", nil];
```

3.13 should be credited to abc@def.com and

0.10 and 0.03 should be credited to def@abc.com

Can anybody give me the detailed explanation about this,

Answer (score 0):

I think don't store emails in array. Just when you using do the following:

```
if ([amount isEqualToString:@"3.13"])
email = @"abc@def.com";
else 
email = @"def@abc.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

Chained Payments only allows **one** amount to **one** email (And all the emails have to be unique)

You would need to total the 2nd and 3rd amounts into a single entry.